# Fill in bash array with script arguments

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, getopts

I got a request to pass a list of ip's as an array in a bash script. For example:

./myscript.sh  192.168.0.1,192.168.0.10,192.168.0.15......

The ip's in the above parameter should properly populate the array present in the bash script. I would like it if anyone can show it in conjunction with the getopts utlity.

FYI - I'm fairly new to bash, so please be understanding......

Comment: Unclear what you're really asking. Please provide more details. As it stands, `"$@"` is sufficient.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove the commas from your input, the `sed` takes care of this.
Then you can create an array with just the `var=()` syntax.

```
#! /bin/bash

no_commas=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/,/ /g'`
ip_array=($no_commas)

for addr in ${ip_array[@]}; do
    echo "Address: $addr"
done
```

Which gives me:

```
$./bash_array.sh 192.168.1.33,192.168.2.3
Address: 192.168.1.33
Address: 192.168.2.3
```

Comment: There some good documentation on this here - https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html